# next previous jquery arrow highlight menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to add a next and previous button under my menu which higlight my items.

When I click on each section with my mouse cursor on my menu, it works. I have each item highlighted.

My problem is like when we click on the next or previous button it doesn't higlight item on my menu.

What is wrong in my Jquery code ?

Here my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/drQ79/1/)

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul id="list">
        <li class='active'><a id="testSlide1" href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="testSlide2" href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="testSlide3" href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a id="testSlide4" href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<nav class="da-arrows">

<button id="PrevButton">Previous</button>
<button id="NextButton">Next</button>
</nav>

<script>
    $("a").click(function(){
      // If this isn't already active
      if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
        // Remove the class from anything that is active
        $("li.active").removeClass("active");
        // And make this active
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
      }
    });

    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    var list = $("#list");
    var li = list.children();
    var lengthMinusOne = li.length - 1;
    var index = 0;
    var num = $("#list li").length;

    var prevLi = $(li[0]).hasClass("active");

    $("#NextButton").click(function(){
       index++;
       if (index > lengthMinusOne) index = 0;
       prevLi.removeClass("active");
       prevLi = $(li[index]).addClass("active");
    });
    $("#PrevButton").click(function(){
       index--;
       if (index < 0) index = lengthMinusOne;
       prevLi.removeClass("active");
       prevLi = $(li[index]).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#NextButton").click(function(){
   index++;
   if (index > lengthMinusOne) index = 0;
   prevLi.removeClass("active");
   prevLi = $(li[index]).addClass("active");
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/tJ9aj/

Comment: Hi RGS,
Txx for your solution, it works well. I actually, wanted to replace button which was for my test by arrows definied on my CSS. Problem it doesn't work anymore. Any idea ?

    <nav class="da-arrows">
    <div id="PrevButton"><span class="da-arrows-prev"></span></div>
    <div id="NextButton"><span class="da-arrows-next"></span></div>
    </nav>

Comment: @user979974, Please wrap div inside anchor tag and set id to anchor tag as 'PrevButton'.

Comment: I changed, $('#NextButton").click(function(){ by $(".da-arrows-next").click(function(){ it seems working. I remove the div id. What do think ? Is it a clean solution ?

Comment: <nav class="da-arrows"><a href="javascript"void(0);" onclick="function name here"><div id="PrevButton"><span class="da-arrows-prev"></span></div></a> <a href="javascript"void(0);" onclick="function name here"><div id="NextButton"><span class="da-arrows-next"></span></div></a> </nav>